# Pass list from python to R through rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to make a simple call to a `R` package (`ks`) from within python through [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/index.html). This is what I would like to achieve:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects

# Define two matrices.
matrix1 = [[1,1,1,1], [3,3,3,3]]
matrix2 = [[1,1,1,1], [3,3,3,3]]

# Call 'ks' function to obtain p_value.
p_val = robjects.r('''
library(ks)
kde.test(x1=matrix1, x2=matrix2)$pvalue''')

print p_val
```

I tried following the [documentation from rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/introduction.html#calling-r-functions) but it is very scarce. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'll have to write a function in python that takes `matrix1` and returns the R code for constructing such matrix: `matrix(c(1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)`. Then replace `matrix1` in the R code by that long string.

Comment: But how would I pass that function to R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting my own answer based on the one given by [lgautier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19737834/1391441) since that one did not work as is. I also made it a bit more general by passing `nrow` instead of having it fixed.

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
ks = importr('ks')

kde_test = ks.kde_test

matr1 = [1., 3., 1., 3., 0.2, 1.5, 0.5, 1.3]
matr2 = [1., 3., 1., 3., 0.2, 1.5, 0.5, 1.3, 0.5, 4.6]  

m1 = robjects.r.matrix(robjects.FloatVector(matr1), nrow=int(len(matr1)/2), byrow=True)
m2 = robjects.r.matrix(robjects.FloatVector(matr2), nrow=int(len(matr2)/2), byrow=True)

res = kde_test(x1 = m1, x2 = m2)

pval = res.rx2('pvalue')

print float(str(pval)[4:])
```

All credit goes to lgautier for proposing the solution even if it did not work at first.

Answer (score 2):

To get [functions in packages](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/robjects_rpackages.html#rpy2.robjects.packages):

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
ks = importr('ks')

kde_test = ks.kde_test
```

To [build matrices](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#matrix):

```
import rpy2.robjects
Matrix = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import IntVector
matrix1 = Matrix( IntVector([1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3]), nrow=2)
matrix2 = Matrix( IntVector([1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3]), nrow=2)
```

To [call functions](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/robjects_functions.html):

```
res = kde_test(x1 = matrix1, x2 = matrix2)
```

To [extract a named element in a list](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-2.3/html/vector.html#extracting-r-style):

```
pval = res.rx2('pvalue')
```

Comment: This returns an error when I run it: `matrix1 = Matrix( [1,1,1,1, 3,3,3,3], nrow=2, byrow=True )
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'byrow'`. Did you try running this code?

Comment: @Gabriel: I made shortcuts, that lead to that error message. This is now edited (note: the documentation in the link is correct though)

Comment: This still returns an error: `rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error en chol.default(S) : la submatriz de orden 3 no es definida positiva`.

Comment: @Gabriel : as it should, and would with the same data (the example data you have chosen in your question) when doing the same in R.

Comment: but I also tried it with the data I used in my answer and it shows the same error where my answer works ok.